# Google Dataflow creates only one worker for large .bz2 file

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, bzip2, bz2

I am trying to process the Wikidata json dump using Cloud Dataflow.

I have downloaded the file from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/latest-all.json.bz2 and hosted it into a GS bucket. It's a large (50G) .bz2 file containing a list of json dicts (one per line).

I understand that apache_beam.io.ReadFromText can handle .bz2 (I tested that on toy datasets) and that .bz2 is splittable. Therefore I was hoping that multiple workers would be created that would work in parallel on different blocks of that unique file (I'm not totally clear if/how blocks would res.

Ultimately I want to do some analytics on each line (each json dict) but as a test for ingestion I am just using the project's wordcount.py:

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
--input gs://MYBUCKET/wikidata/latest-all.json.bz2 \
--output gs://MYBUCKET/wikidata/output/entities-all.json \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--project MYPROJECT \
--temp_location gs://MYBUCKET/tmp/
```

At startup, autoscaling quickly increases the number of workers 1->6 but only one worker does any work and then autoscaling scales back 6->1 after a couple minutes (jobid: 2018-10-11_00_45_54-9419516948329946918)

If I disable autoscaling and set explicitly the number of workers, then all but one remain idle.

Can parallelism be achieved on this sort of input? Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You are probably a victim of fusion optimization, try to do GroupBy with custom trigger (which will emit groups as soon as they are available). You can get inspired here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.java
Basically - you need to do Reshuffle transform, because fusion optimization causes all steps to happen on single machine instead of distributing them.

Comment: @MarcinZablocki thanks for the quick answer. I read about about "preventing fusion" here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization. While I'm not too sure yet about how to implement your solution with triggers, I injected a shuffle transform beam.Reshuffle() right after ReadFromText(). I understand that should prevent fusion. Is that correct? Unfortunately that does not seem to change anything. Workers 1->6->1 within a few minutes for example on 2018-10-11_07_20_38-9840705006566518535.

Answer (score 0):

Other than Hadoop, Apache Beam has not yet implemented bzip2 splitting: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-683